# Why does sp_columns show 'image' as the type_name of a varbinary(max) type?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I ran `sp_columns SomeTable` on a table on my local computer, and was confused by the output for a column that should be a `varbinary(max)` column:

```
TABLE_QUALIFIER  TABLE_OWNER TABLE_NAME    COLUMN_NAME  DATA_TYPE TYPE_NAME  PRECISION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MDB              dbo         SomeTable     SomeColumn   -4        image      2147483647
```

The confusing part is that this column is a varbinary(max) column, but the `TYPE_NAME` listed here is `image`.

So my question is this: Why is `sp_columns` listing this as an `image` when it is a `varbinary(max)`?

This is on `Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU5) (KB4040714) - 13.0.4451.0 (X64)`

Comment: Since `sp_columns` dates back to SQL Server 6.0 ([Ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226174%28v=sql.70%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).) it probably carries some baggage along from Ye Good Olde Days. Rather than change the result returned and breaking existing code, it simply continues to return a now deprecated type. _They_ have plenty of other ways of breaking existing code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this. I'm guessing because `IMAGE` is defined as

```
Variable-length binary data from 0 through 2^31-1
```

which is the same as `VARBINARY(MAX)`.

Changing `MAX` to any other value changes it from image to `VARBINARY`

Comment: I guess that makes sense. It's just bizzare since image is a deprecated type in the newest version of tsql.

Answer (score 0):

I always prefer to use the `sys` catalog views to inspect those kind of things about my db objects - and here, I do get `varbinary` as the type name, and `-1` as the `max_length` (signifying `varbinary(max)`):

```
SELECT
    TableName = t.Name, 
    ColumnName = c.Name, 
    TypeName = ty.Name,
    c.max_length
FROM sys.tables t 
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.types ty ON ty.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
WHERE t.name = 'SomeTable'
  AND c.name = 'SomeColumn'
```